# Spring integration http disable multipart in get requests

Tags: spring, rest, http, integration, multipart

I have a problem with sending GET requests to my HTTP resource. I can't control the client side requests and Spring seems to think that they want to do multipart requests. But they don't do that, they are just sending me JSON in the payload.

It works fine in POST requests but in GET requests I receive an empty LinkedMultiValueMap. I have tried a few methods but I wasn't able to disable the multipart feature.

```
<int:channel id="myChannel" />
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="myChannel"
                          supported-methods="GET,POST"
                          path="/testResource"
                          request-payload-type="java.util.Map">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator ref="TestEndPoint"
                       method="testMethod"
                       input-channel="myChannel" />

<bean id="TestEndPoint" class="com.example.TestEndPoint" />
```

This is my test method:

```
public Message<?> testMethod(Message<Map> message)
{
     Map payload = message.getPayload();

     // Do stuff with the payload, create a result...

     return MessageBuilder.withPayload(result)
            .setHeader(HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, HttpStatus.OK)
            .build();
}
```

How can I disable the multipart feature or is there a better way to handle this?

Note: I'm aware of this property but it does not fix the problem:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false
```

Comment: ***It works fine in POST requests but in GET requests I receive an empty LinkedMultiValueMap***- what is in your map? `requestparam` or `requestBody`? Btw, you can't send data in body in `GET` method.

Comment: Nothing is in the map that I receive in the message function but it should contain the requestBody. I suspected that payloads don't work in GET requests but is there anything that I can do to catch this error?

Comment: no, you can't send payload I mean anything on `requestBody` in `GET`. Either `requestParam`, `pathvariable` or in headers. Otherwise do it in `POST` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [Ref](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) :

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

So, you must send your payload in `POST` to be working perfectly.